# Add a character to a specific position of a string only if the string is > a particular length

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a tablet that has a column whose data looks like this:

```
A785
B21423
21432
031258A
358
Z94
```

I want to add a '.' as the 4th character only if the original string has 4 or more characters which would result in:

```
A78.5
B21.423
214.32
031.258A
358
Z94
```

I'm doing this in SQL server management studio 18

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
select (case when len(str) >= 4
             then stuff(str, 4, 0, '.')
             else str
        end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the followinh solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, token VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tbl (token) VALUES
('A785'),
('B21423'),
('21432'),
('031258A'),
('358'),
('Z94');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT *
    , IIF(size > 3, CONCAT(LEFT(token, 3), '.', RIGHT(token, size - 3))
        , token) AS tokenNew
FROM @tbl 
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEN(token)) AS t(size);
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------+------+----------+
| ID |  token  | size | tokenNew |
+----+---------+------+----------+
|  1 | A785    |    4 | A78.5    |
|  2 | B21423  |    6 | B21.423  |
|  3 | 21432   |    5 | 214.32   |
|  4 | 031258A |    7 | 031.258A |
|  5 | 358     |    3 | 358      |
|  6 | Z94     |    3 | Z94      |
+----+---------+------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you, that does work, but I was hoping to do it without having to create a new table first.

Comment: @Freonthewhite, you don't need to create a new DB table. I provided you a minimal reproducible example. You copy it as-as to SSMS and it works. You just need to use the `SELECT` statement, and modify it for your real DB table name, and its columns.

Comment: @Freonthewhite, if the proposed solution is working for you, please don't forget to mark it as Answer.